# Does this X.org Modeline look right?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I inherited an unusual custom monitor from a defunct department in my company. I did manage to get instructions on how to set up the timings using the NVIDIA Control Panel in Windows as shown here:
[image: Monitor timing config]

As you can see in the screenshot, the monitor is 3840x720 and 60Hz and the manual timings are:

|  | Horizontal | Vertical |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Active pixels | 3840 | 720 |
| Front porch (pixels) | 96 | 6 |
| Sync width (pixels) | 10 | 10 |
| Total pixels | 4040 | 760 |
| Polarity | Negative (-) | Negative (-) |
| Refresh rate | 45.60 KHz | 60 Hz |

And a 184.2240 MHz pixel clock calculated.

This works for Windows but I'd like to use this monitor in Linux. This is the Modeline I came up with:

```
Modeline "3840x720_60.00"  184.224  3840 3936 3946 4040  720 726 736 760 -hsync -vsync
```

But it doesn't seem to work (the monitor shows a rainbow test pattern when I turn it on which seems like what it does when there's no input).

I've read a couple of explanations of how to generate the Modeline such as this [article](https://nyanpasu64.gitlab.io/blog/crt-modeline-cvt-interlacing)

But I think--the way Modelines are defined--a better way to think of the porches and sync would be like this:

[image: Timing diagram]

FYI, I'm testing this with Ubuntu 23.10 and an RTX 4060 with NVIDIA driver 535. But I can try different Ubuntu's or even different hardware if that might make things easier.